# Pass PHP array to external jQuery $.ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Basically what I want to do is get an array that has t.php, and alert it with JavaScript with the response of t.php.

The problem is that the variable doesn't exist in this file...
So, how you can pass this variable to JS?

I tried with 'return':

```
return $sqlData = $q->query_array_assoc();
```

But doesn't work.

Here is my $.ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#brand').change(function(e){
    console.log(e);
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "t.php",
        data: { type: 1, brand: this.value }
    })
    .done(function(msg){
        $('#debug').html(msg);
        var pArray = <?php echo json_encode($sqlData);?>
        for (var i = 0; i < pArray.length; i++) {
            alert(pArray[i]);
        };
});
});
</script>
```

Note: I sent

```
data: { type: 1, brand: this.value }
```

To validate a switch statement in the .php file, but there isn't problem with that. I get the data from the database and fetch in the variable `$sqlData;`

So the array has data, the problem is get it with `$.ajax`

Comment: not possible. HTTP doesn't know anything about php structures, it only does "bytes". a php array in such a chunk of bytes would be the literal word "Array". you need to serialize/encode your array. for JS, the easiest method is `json_encode()`. and note that your php snippet in the JS code is  pointless. that PHP executes **ONCE** when the page is generated, and never again.

Comment: Also, you should use the 'echo' or 'print' instead of 'return' in 't.php' for return some result for your js =)

Comment: Ok, so... How suppose you can make an nested select with a MySQL query? You have an idea how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your php file, you need to echo instead of return

```
echo json_encode($q->query_array_assoc());
```

in javascript code:

```
$.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "t.php",
        data: { type: 1, brand: this.value },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#debug').html(data);
            // if you want to use it as array
            var json_data = JSON.parse(data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: When I do this, then Chrome Debugger show an error on the first line... <!DOCTYPE html>
...

Comment: that's because you have that line in the html head, not because of the ajax, and it shouldn't have any effect on the output.

Comment: Yes, but it refers to the FIRST line, it doesn't matter if you wrote <html> instance of <!DOCTYPE html>, it always show that error.

Comment: can you check the actual output of ajax call, if it shows what you wanted then the error must come from another section of the code.

Comment: You're right @lightbringer. Now I just have to deal with the JSON to put it into the DOM, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Make 2 files please, a "t.php" file and a "t.html" file and add my code there. Run the code and see response. You just have to work with the response to get the values se perated by comma "," !!!

/******************** UPDATED ***********************/

//t.php

```html
<?php
$a = array();
$a[]=1;
$a[]=2;
$a[]=3;
echo "$a[0],$a[1],$a[2]";
?>
```

//t.html

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


function fun(){
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "t.php",
        data: { },
        dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
        success: function(response){                    
  //$("#debug").html(response); //Outputs the html of php file into #dialog div
   alert(response);
     document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = (response); //Outputs the html of php file into #dialog div
  }
    })

}
</script>

<button onclick="fun()">Call Ajax Fun</button>

<div id="debug"></div>
```

Did this help?

Comment: Yes, that what I want to do. So must be .html file?